# Edit plugin filter

Tags: plugins, filters

I am trying to edit a filter that is added from a plugin, without editing the plugin itself. The plugin in question is Gravity Forms User Registration.

I have found the filter function in the plugin code, and I am currently trying to remove it in order to add it again with my changes. However, I can't figure out how to remove the filter. When removing actions, i usually hook in to the same hook with a lower priority and remove it from there. However, this seems different.

Filter is added like this:

```
/**
 * Initializes GFAddon and adds the actions that we need
 *
 * @see GFAddon
 */
public function init() {

[...]
    add_filter( 'gform_validation',                   array( $this, 'validate' ) );
[...]
```

Should I create a new instance of something for '$this', and how do I from which hook to call my removal function?

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint...

In your case, I'll try to remove the filter

```
remove_filter( 'gform_validation', array( 'classname', 'validate' ) );
```

Rename classname with the class name where the filter is.

And add your filter and functions

```
add_filter( 'gform_validation', 'your_validate' ) );
```

If you want to access to another class (and public function) : `classname::validate();`

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. But how do I figure out the classname?

Comment: at the top of the file where stand the public function class GFaddon{ ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I cant get it to work though..

`add_action('wp_head', 'test_remove');

function test_remove() {
 remove_filter( 'gform_validation', array( 'GF_User_Registration', 'validate' ) );
}`

I have tried with GF_User_Registration(), new GF_User_Registration() and $global GF_User_Registration as well..

Comment: Try add_action('init' ... Instead of wp_head

Comment: And remove_filter directly not in function ?

Comment: Maybe I should use something like `remove_filter( 'gform_validation', array( GFForms::GF_User_Registration(), 'validate' ) );`?

Comment: Directly without function doesnt work either.

Comment: I don't use thiis plugin. It's hard for me to help you, i don't know which plugin add-on you're working with.

Comment: Yes , if you place the remove_filter directly in functions.php it's good too